# Change MaterialUI icons font size in css

Tags: html, css, icons, material-ui

So here I am trying to increase my icons value 200px, but by default its taking `24px`. 24px is the the default for all icon in google icons. So any suggestion!

**HTML**

```html
<div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
  <i class="material-icons abcd">featured_play_list</i>
  <h3>BBBB BBB BBBB</h3>
  <p>
    XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX
  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.abcd{
    font-size: 200px;
    display: block;
    color:#e67e22;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: In your css you have to write `.abcd{`. Don't forget the dot that say that `abcd` is a class

Comment: Why have you remove the error from question? Anyone re-reading this question will not understand the comments or answers at all.

Comment: yes. i have wrote that. i forget to mention here. its following the color and margin-bottom property but not the font-size and display property. in case of those two property its using its own default value.

Comment: If you write `font-size: 200px !important;` does it change something ?

Comment: @johannchopin It does. issue solve. can you please explain me what is the real issue and what is !important ?

Comment: I updated my answer ;) Can you please check it and `validate` it so everyone knows that this answer fixed your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MaterialUI icons use the default size `24px`. If you want to change this size without using the icons size classes provided by M-UI like `.md-18`, you will have to use the `!important` rule:

```css
.abcd{
    font-size: 200px !important;
    display: block;
    color:#e67e22;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```